# Pointers for a web sniffer/auto responder

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking to make a simple web traffic sniffer that will automatically reply to authentication requests from a predefined source, but I'm not entirely sure how to start/what I am looking at my self here.

I guess it's easier to explain if you have a short backstory;
I use WebDAV, but Windows does NOT have good support for this (lacking Basic auth support, and Digest support being flawed at best), so you are forced to manually authenticate with a username and password every time you open a file, when you start your computer or a word document (for example) loads resource such as images (imagine writing yoru username and password for every image in a powerpoint!).

I've found a brilliant program that does this for me called WebDrive, but it's a commercial product with way more options then I really need, so I'm looking to make my own small lightweight wrapper that'll just sit nicely in the background (maybe even just as a service?) and listen for when an authentication request is sent from my server and then respond for me.

Could someone be so kind as to point me in the right direction here, as it would be a real time saver if I had a general idea of what I was looking for when I write this.

Comment: http://www.fiddler2.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need is available in the public domain.

First off, to create a windows service, you can really just use the windows service template in Visual Studio.  However doing this does mean that you'll have a few challenges to overcome, not least in the debugging and testing space.

My recommendation, is to use topshelf ( http://topshelf-project.com/ ) I've just started using this for all my windows service projects, and to say it makes service development easy is an understatement.

Once you have a service up and running, then you need to be able to capture network packets.

As many Sys Admins and devs will tell you capture apps generally don't get much better that wireshark.

The interface behind this "WinPCap" now has a .NET project that can be used from within C# or VB and can be found at ( http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sharppcap/index.php?title=Main_Page )

Using the 2 of these together you should be able to hook something up to perform the task you need.